# Django doesn't recognise keyword blank on child of forms.Form

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-forms, django-1.4

I'm trying to create a form that will receive empty strings in some of its values. This form is not backed by a model object. I've defined it thus:

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    device = fields.CharField(blank=True)
    min_release_date = fields.CharField(blank=True)
    price_range = fields.CharField(blank=True)
    has_in_app_purchases = fields.CharField(blank=True)
```

Except when I try to run a test:

```
def test_valid_no_data(self):
    from webanalytics.web.search import ANY_PRICE, DEFAULT_DATES, HAS_IAP_IDS
    form_data = {
        'price_range': ANY_PRICE[0],
        'min_release_date': DEFAULT_DATES[0],
        'has_in_app_purchases': HAS_IAP_IDS[0]
    }
    search = SearchForm(form_data)
    self.assertTrue(search.is_valid())
```

I get the following exception:

```
ERROR: Failure: TypeError (__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'blank')
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/loader.py", line 411, in loadTestsFromName
    addr.filename, addr.module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/importer.py", line 47, in importFromPath
    return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/importer.py", line 94, in importFromDir
    mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
  File "/workspace/aa/tests/ci/unit/webanalytics/web/test_forms.py", line 5, in <module>
    from webanalytics.forms import SearchForm
  File "/workspace/aa/webanalytics/forms.py", line 8, in <module>
    class SearchForm(forms.Form):
  File "/workspace/aa/webanalytics/forms.py", line 15, in SearchForm
    device = fields.CharField(blank=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/fields.py", line 187, in __init__
    super(CharField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'blank'
```

According to the docs this should be ok. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because Django form fields don't accept a `blank` parameter.

The [core parameters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/fields/#core-field-arguments) accepted by Django form fields are:

- required
- label
- label_suffix
- initial
- widget
- help_text
- error_messages
- validators
- localize

  You can instead pass  a `required` parameter with its value as `False`. So, if you pass an empty value – either `None` or the empty string `""`, the form will not raise a validation error.

Answer (score 1):

No, the docs do not mention a `blank` parameter for form fields; that's for model fields.

Form fields take a [`required` parameter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/fields/#required) that defaults to True.